# PostgreSQL: Query that splits array into elements

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQl, so perhaps this is a basic question:
I have a table with a field of data type text[], that is an array of text strings. This SQL command

```
Select "Table"."Field" From "Table";
```

returns values in the form of arrays, e.g. {AA,BB} and {AA,CC}.

Now I am using the SQL editor in pgAdmin trying to write an SQL command that will select the values and split them into single elements. I have tried a construction like

```
    Select "Table"."Field[1]", "Table"."Field[2]" From "Table";
```

but it does not function. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

see this example:

create table:

```
CREATE TABLE array_tab (   ar text[] )
```

insert example date:

```
insert into array_tab (ar) select string_to_array('aa~^~bb~^~cc', '~^~')
```

select date that you need:

```
select ar[1],ar[2],ar[3] from array_tab ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes `"` surround the object names. Your mistake is to put the square brackets inside the double quotes, so PostgreSQL is looking for a table field called `Field[1]` istead of the first element of field `Field`.

You should write:

```
SELECT "Table"."Field"[1]
```

I would really recommend that you never use anything but lower case characters, numbers and the underscore `_` in table names. It makes life so much easier, because you avoid all the quoting problems.